# MP3 frames in an AVI file

Tags: data-structures, mp3, avi

I have read the following document to understand how is structured an AVI file :
http://www.alexander-noe.com/video/documentation/avi.pdf

An AVI file is a container of streams.
An AVI file can contain a MP3 audio stream.
Here is how I have understood data structures of a MP3 audio stream in an AVI file :

[image]

I have also read the following web page to understand how is structured a MP3 file :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure

So a MP3 file is a sequence of MP3 frames.
Each MP3 frame is made up of a header and data.

To create a MP3 file from a MP3 stream in an AVI file I guess that MP3 headers can be built up with data contained in the MPEGLAYER3FORMAT structure.
But I am wondering if 1 audio chunk structure matches data of 1 MP3 frame.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but for other coders, a really good way to obtain a specific multimedia format without reading the AVI or the MP3 bible is to play with ffmpeg.

1. Choose an MP3 file from 10 seconds.
2. Choose a video exactly in the codec you want to use.
3. Mix them using this command:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i mysound.mp3 -i myvideo.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy myResult.avi
   ```

...then observe how the mp3 has been placed in the AVI file using an hexadecimal editor.

You'll notice that the sound has been placed in several chunks after each video frame, and that an index has been built at the end of the AVI for both the image frames and the audio samples. Once you're comfortable with the notion of index in this specific context (with this specific codec mixed with an MP3), then you can build your files by copying this pattern.